# Magento - Adding page number to title on products listing

Tags: php, magento

I have an extension that uses the products list block to show the products grid filter by an attribute (the extension is [Attribute Info Pages](http://blog.zenyooo.com/blog/2011/11/13/magento-shop-by-manufacturerbrandcharacteretc-%E2%80%93-attribute-info-pages/)).

In the "_prepareLayout" function of this extension block the extension sets the page's title and description using this code :

```
$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
.
.
.
$head->setTitle($title);
head->setDescription($des);
```

I want to add text to the title and description in this format :

```
$page_info = "Page A of B for ";
$title = $page_info . title;
$items_info = "Listings X-Y (out of Z) ";
$des = items_info . $des;
```

I've tried this code it order to get the current page, last page, number and items and so on :

```
$html_pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager');
    $html_pager->setCollection($product_collection);
    $limit = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest()->getParam('limit');
    if(empty($limit))
    {
        $limit = 8;
    }

    $html_pager->setLimit($limit);
    $LastPageNumber = $html_pager->getLastPageNum();
    $current_page = $html_pager->getCurrentPage();

    $page_info = "";
    if($current_page > 1)
    {
        $page_info = "Page " . $current_page . " of $LastPageNumber for ";
    }

    $FirstNum = $html_pager->getFirstNum();
    $LastNum = $html_pager->getLastNum();
    $TotalNum = $html_pager->getTotalNum();

    $items_info = "Listings " . $FirstNum . "-" . $LastNum . " (out of ". $TotalNum . ") ";
```

The code gives me the correct information but it causes a problem in the products grid - it always shows 10 products in the products grid (no matter what I choose in "Show per page").

Any ideas how to get the information without breaking the grid functionality?

Comment: It seems to me your problem related with singleton function which you specified some criteria in there, therefore the returning only one object based on those criterias. This can be breake a page size.

Comment: I'm setting a product collection and a limit to the singleton object, but they are the same product collection and limit the grid should use, so it doesn't supposed to cause a problem. Is there a different way to get this information?

Comment: Same output, but with in build functions

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15544361/1425779

Comment: I think this way is more suitable for get page navigation.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15544361/1425779

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
    $product_collection = clone Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection(); 
    $total = count($product_collection);

    $current_page = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();

    $limit = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest()->getParam('limit');
    if(empty($limit))
    {
        $limit = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
    }

    $pages = $total / $limit;
    $pages = ceil($pages);

    if($current_page > 1)
    {
        $page_info = "Page " . $current_page . " of $pages for ";
    }

    $FirstNum = $limit*($current_page-1)+1;

    if($current_page == $pages)
    {
        $LastNum = $total;
    }
    else
    {
        $LastNum = $limit + ($FirstNum - 1);
    }

    $items_info = "Listings " . $FirstNum . "-" . $LastNum . " (out of ". $total . ") ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager');
$productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();
$pager->setCollection($productCollection);
```

After that, you have got all the block's method available (Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager) :

```
$pager->getCurrentPage();
$pager->getLastPageNum();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.