# Magento pagination products

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a problem with Magento pagination.

The prudct list page i call by my XML is:

```
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="categorieen" as="categorieen" translate="label" template="page/html/categorieen.phtml">
        <label>Categorieën</label>
    </block>
```

The code of my product list page is:

```
    <div id="products">
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();?>


    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
         <?php

         $pic = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->keepFrame(false)->resize(170);
         ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>">
         <div class="block_prod">
           <div class="block_image_prod"><img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>"></div>
           <div class="block_title_prod"><h2><?php echo strtoupper($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())); ?></h2></div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <?php $i++; endforeach ?>


<?php 

/*
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO.'/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();*/

/* Provide a known category id that has children as a test */
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$curent_cat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();
$curent_cat_id = $curent_cat->getId();

$id = $curent_cat_id;

/* Load category by id*/
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);


/*Returns comma separated ids*/
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

//Print out categories string
#print_r($subcats);

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive() && !$_category->getIncludeInMenu())
  {
    $caturl     = $_category->getURL();
    $catname     = $_category->getName();
    if($_category->getImageUrl())
    {
      $catimg     = $_category->getImageUrl();
    }
?>
         <a href="<?php echo $caturl; ?>">
         <div class="block_prod">
           <div class="block_image_prod"><img src="<?php  echo $catimg; ?>"></div>
           <div class="block_title_prod"><h2><?php echo strtoupper($catname); ?></h2></div>
        </div>
        </a>

<?php    

    }
}?>
</div>
    <div i="toolbar-bottom">
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
    </div>
```

On my product page i included the toolbar with

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
```

But i don't get an pagination like

```
1-2-3-4...12
```

I only get :

```
Show 30 per page
```

Is there an solution fot this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the default `catalog.xml` you will see that the toolbar is included as follows:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

Have you included it in a similar way?

The other place to look is is `toolbar.phtml` to see if everything you require is included there.

Comment: Hey Alex, i tried this but nothing appear with this method. The toolbar works but the pager doesn't appear. In the code  toolbar.phtml i find this code:<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>. But it is empty.

Comment: can you post your toolbar.phtml?

Comment: Also, I assume you have more than one page worth of items to show otherwise it obviously wouldn't show it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for some one

```
<?php $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock()->setCollection($_productCollection);
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->setLimit($toolbar->getLimit())->setCollection($_productCollection);
if ($toolbar->getCollection()->getSize() > 0):?>
<?php if (!$pager->isFirstPage()): ?>
    <a class="prev-page" href="<?php echo $pager->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">Previous</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="prev-page disabled">&nbsp;PreviousDisable</span>
<?php endif; ?>

<span class="current-page-detail">
    Page <?php echo $pager->getCurrentPage(); ?> of <?php echo $pager->getLastPageNum(); ?>
</span>

<?php if (!$pager->isLastPage()): ?>
    <a class="next-page" href="<?php echo $pager->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">&nbsp;Next</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="next-page disabled">&nbsp;NextDisable</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 46 products in the category and some products are hidden. The code of the toolbar:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
?>
<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="pager">
        <p class="amount">
            <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>

        <div class="limiter">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>

    </div>

    <?php if( $this->isExpanded() ): ?>
    <div class="sorter">
        <?php if( $this->isEnabledViewSwitcher() ): ?>
        <p class="view-mode">
            <?php $_modes = $this->getModes(); ?>
            <?php if($_modes && count($_modes)>1): ?>
            <label><?php echo $this->__('View as') ?>:</label>
            <?php foreach ($this->getModes() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
                <?php if($this->isModeActive($_code)): ?>
                    <strong title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></strong>&nbsp;
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getModeUrl($_code) ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></a>&nbsp;
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```